# iOS In App Purchase Restore from Other App

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an app with an In App Purchase (App A). I want now to create a new app (with a new App Identifier and Profile -> App B), but I want a user who payed for the iAP in App A to be able to restore it in App B.

Is that scenario possible?

I guess it isn't for the following reasons:

- iAP Identifier is bound to an App Identifier and cannot exist twice
- When a user tries to restore the iAP Purchase, the call only checks within the configured iAP purchase Identifiers of the given App Identifiers and not globally

Has anyone had such a scenario before?  How did you solve it?

Comment: Should not be possible as purchase receipts are stored within the app container (sandboxing)  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the desired functionality with the help of your server.

You can keep track of whether user has purchased something or not on your server.

So when he logs in to app A, you can check with your server about his purchase status. If he has purchasd using app B then you can provide him with unlocked content on app A also or vice versa. In case, he hasn't purchased anything, then show him the option of buying.

Comment: Also thought of solving it this way via my Parse backend. The only issue is that my users are anonymous. I would have to force all users to register as users in an update of my App A, then only publish App B... That been said I guess I'll do it this way, as I prefer it over being shit stormed by the users because they lost their iAP. I'll vote your answer up

Comment: Hey @DonBaron, I am trying to follow a similar procedure but am worried whether Apple might reject it. How did it go for you? Did Apple pose any problem in this approach?